# Where can I find a collection of new errata for EGA?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, soft-question, errata

There is an extensive list of EGA's errata on the books themselves, but my question is whether new errata, that is those found by various mathematicians after the publication, are collected somewhere.
A search on Google did not reveal anything on the subject, but it seems reasonable that such a list may exist and I'm simply not managing to find it.

Comment: On the other hand, there does exist a combined table of contents, prepared by David Madore, http://perso.telecom-paristech.fr/~madore/ega-toc.pdf

Comment: @ACL: I was aware of it but thanks for pointing it out, I agree it is extremely useful

Answer (score 3):

In the years since this question was asked, such a collection of errata has begun to be built, thanks to the community project https://github.com/ryankeleti/ega

At the moment of writing, they have finished translating EGA I and II, and are working through III. They have also included an "Errata and addenda (list 1)" and have plans for lists 2 and 3 relating to EGA III and IV. Hopefully this will satisfy the OP once the project is completed.

Comment: I'm not sure this is actually an answer to the question: the errata in that translation (even those still yet to be translated) are simply from the versions of EGA found on Numdam, e.g. the Errata for EGA I are found on p.214 of the PDF copy of EGA II (http://www.numdam.org/item/?id=PMIHES_1961__8__5_0)